# Safari on macOS is not showing my images but chrome and safari mobile does

Tags: html, image, vue.js, safari

In my Vuejs (2.6.11) App, I am displaying images from Google Cloud Storage this way (result of v-for):

```
<img slot="image" class="card-img-top" :src="img_basepath + result.header_img" alt="Card image cap" >
```

While everything works fine in Chrome and Safari on iOS, the images are broken on Safari 13.1 and show blue squares with question mark:

[image]

If I check the HTML using Safari's inspect tool it shows the following:

```
<div class="card-image">
<img src="https://storage.cloud.google.com/heavnt-test/artistes/May2020/xoGD1P848Id9dmSrLJWX.png" alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top">
</div>
```

And if check the resources loaded, I got this:

[image]

Of course, the link is working ([check it here](https://00e9e64baca5a875668a1a87c563d9d1a8f18ea8511edb8c61-apidata.googleusercontent.com/download/storage/v1/b/heavnt-test/o/artistes%2FMay2020%2FxoGD1P848Id9dmSrLJWX.png?qk=AD5uMEtu6IDmnHE-DUQ0aVNgmQR87YfZVoYVbCvkKFaaGeAWfLdJQ7sjWjCjIB8WN6yR3JvPD4hnqt8xJq1DjUDp7fmB2L6AcAqtHeiPShadk7d3me4BhNIw4VfBwX_QRpyyq0GfM4oqtzXMchafZFopbNRClPKI-6YZWKExyLTBiYOpZOEU8cp4EIpVlNDnG9uunLf0rLoGJhJUoWUkVZx7r6BLlu5rHua4B1LZayTC2dG5EDdDCT9ozVfZvdjQb7M3lns_dLVFH1MnPBykvHYU9wVAue07tLym3EmpddetRPwG5ExEkUvxa8t_Mjy-Vuz3LhGtwFm-0iNoUvyQXFdFKD1XTAEDC1Bz6U_LXby8qlU3m05WRmdaQYT3kZ2nVdcGA0IMnPZnRppa8H1kqfBxcknaWlDCpsNETqbf9XEaT2LdeyokS-2Qcq-UH89Y7yPtEp6i7AJRDWdr85qU694NqI1W1JyPBFdwg3fZtAvdKOeS5qPZQYz7mUR3k1migNK4ZjScEcAwcn_pni6PzNoXytYkFQqidyZavFbLCpryk-TWSd3N2RPRRx6XLP6_DH1liDR4oF2wkx_lhQVGRGrFo_r18D2VJwJd3cSlou0Gp-BQrM_N66Au8YDitLmK8zdYgXkJX8kExYhgk56gdzvqpCM7_iynR5fP3Bkoy2VHcnumu1Zj7O-MOygvCOSDnV5g4m0OlQD4Fo7Mk0tteaSZjtgRS4dfYiiN6kewa-ycivAeXtTTS4ygH5z2vUR1XrMrtz84ElgMwdBpfpAe6Wxq9ITFaZPlJ03AcaR3bzG2J8neg0D5cKruKfbxDmK_G3gENx4deK29eIVT5ugPv6QyEOjwuHtLNA&isca=1)) and, by itself, load fine in Safari.

As it's the only browser where it is not working, I have no idea where to look to fix this issue.

EDIT 24/05/20 @ 14:14

If I login in my App using firebase Auth, then the images loads .. Do not help me to know what's wrong but if it can help any one to tell me ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find out it was because I used a bucket like in the form of:

`https://storage.cloud.google.com/<bucket name>/<file name>`

which require to be logged with a google account, so it was working on chrome because I was logged while not on Safari.

To properly access my Cloud Storage public files I needed to use:

`https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket name>/<file name>`

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution! I had the exact same problem and you saved me a lot of time. GCP docs *eyeroll*.